# Where is the Lightning Web Component developer guide?

Tags: documentation, lightning-web-components

Initially Lightning Web Components was announced with a blog post.

There is also a trailhead [project](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/12/introducing-lightning-web-components.html) and sample [apps](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/sample-gallery).

But I don't see anything in the developer documentation [portal](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/) if I just want to read through the documentation.

Comment: Hey Pete, thanks for spreading the good word on this feature. I realize "heck" is quite mild, but please refrain from cursing of any kind while on this site (or Meta) regardless. It is non-content, and both posts and their titles should be limited to only information which is actually relevant to what is being asked. Thanks! Keep up the good work!

Comment: Sure thing, Adrian.

Comment: The developer documentation portal now contains a link to the Lightning Web Components Developer Guide. If you're looking through the list of dev guides at developer.salesforce.com/docs, you will find Lightning Web Components Developer Guide.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of this in the question. After reaching out to the docs team about this, they were able to add a stub in the docs portal so that it is reachable from everywhere.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The developer guide for lightning web components is located in the component library. There is a public URL for this here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library

In addition to the developer guide, new LWC features in the component library also include a new JS playground tool for prototyping LWC code and a resources tab to quickly take you to common resources.

[image]

There is currently no plan to house the LWC developer guide in the docs portal going forward.

---

**Update**

You no longer need to be logged into a pre-release org to access the component library. The component library public URL now supports direct access to the lightning web component developer [guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc) along with the new playground [tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground).

<strike>**!!!!! Spring 19 Pre-Release Note !!!!!**</strike>

During the pre-release period in order to see the LWC features of the component library, you must access the relative URL from an authenticated org session of a *Spring 19 pre-release org*. If you go directly to the public URL, you will see the component library of the current GA release, Winter 19:

[image]

Simply log into your pre-release org, then append the following onto the host-name of your org:

```
/docs/component-library/overview/components
```

Once Spring 19 goes GA, in February, the LWC features will become available in all instances when accessing the component library.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation is available on this URL

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc

Answer (score 1):

Please check here at that time!
Doc: Lightning Web Components Developer Guide (available after December 17th)
[image: Lightning Web Components Developer Guide]