# Unable to resolve c-hello-world from root/app while creating Hello World for LWC (Lightning Web Components)

Tags: lightning-web-components

I was trying to implement a basic hello world Lightning Web Component in the playground using this link in the component library - https://gs0.lightning.force.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.install_playground but I keep getting this error and I have followed the steps exactly as stated. (copy-paste)

> Unable to resolve c-hello-world from root/app

[image]

Anybody else tried this yet?

Comment: If you have issues accessing the playground: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/242603/where-is-the-lightning-web-component-developer-guide (not necessarily you OP, just anyone who doesn't know what to do because your link wont work for everyone)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Salesforce Developer here. The LWC playground has been fixed. Give it a try!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. When I name my lwc helloWorld (camel case) and reference it in the app html as kebab-case, I get an error in the preview window:

Unable to resolve c-hello-world from root/app

If I change the camel case to all lowercase, and remove the hyphen when referencing it in the app, it works just fine.

I’ve reported.

Comment: And how would you resolve the problem with the firstName variable? import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
    @api firstName;
}

Comment: Because using firstname instead did not work in my case.